# Signed distance along a rotated coordinate

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

On page 4032 of [this paper on CAT scan](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/99e1/126f7f554b8ba02e3f5e0cacb04fe4b8f61a.pdf) there is a distance $d_{ij}$ calculated I presume in the direction of the axis $r$ with the following formula

> ... $d_{ij} = r_i - x_j \cos \theta_i - y_j \sin\theta_i$ is the signed distance
>   between the projection strip $h_i$ and the $j$-th grid point
>   $(x_j,y_j)$ as shown in Fig. 2.

[image]

> What is the geometrical reasoning behind $d_{ij} = r_i - x_j \cos \theta_i - y_j \sin\theta_i$?

I'm asking because considering the rotation matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & - \sin \theta\\ \sin\theta& \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}$$

the $x_j$ coordinate would rotate to $x_j\cos\theta -y_j\sin\theta,$ and therefore, the distance would be

$$d_{ij}=r_i-x_j\cos\theta +y_j\sin\theta$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This distance is measured parallel to $r$, which is perpendicular to $h_i$, so it’s just the difference between $r_i$, and the (signed) length of the orthogonal projection of $p_j=(x_j,y_j)$ onto $r$ a.k.a. the *scalar projection* of $p_j$ onto $r$. The unit vector in the direction of $r$ is $u=(\cos\theta_i,\sin\theta_i)$, so this projection is equal to $(x_j,y_j)\cdot(\cos\theta_i,\sin\theta_i)$, leading directly to the formula $$r_i-x_j\cos\theta_i-y_j\sin\theta_i.$$

You can also derive this formula via a rotation, as you attempted to do, but note that you need to rotate through an angle of $-\theta_i$ instead, which maps $(x_j,y_j)$ to $(x_j\cos\theta_i+y_j\sin\theta_i,-x_j\sin\theta_i+y_j\cos\theta_i)$.

Comment: This is a great explanation, but I don't get why the angle is $-\theta$ since the matrix that I used was to rotate points counterclockwise, and we'd be moving from the standard Cartesian coordinates to a coordinate system where both x and y are rotated counterclockwise by $\theta.$

Comment: @Butternut The matrix you used rotates the _coordinate axes_ counterclockwise by $\theta$. To get the coordinates of a point in this new coordinate system, however, you have to apply the _inverse_ transformation to the original coordinates. You can view this as leaving the coordinate axes fixed and rotating everything so that $r$ aligns with the positive $x$-axis in order to be able to read the distance measured along $r$ from the $x$-coordinate of the point. The same underlying principle is at work when you shift the graph of $y=f(x)$ to the right $a$ units by _subtracting_ $a$ from $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The line going through the point $(x_j,y_j)$ and parallel to the strip $h_i$ is given by

$$(y-y_j)=-\frac{1}{\tan\theta_i}(x-x_j)$$

or,

$$ y\tan\theta_i + x - (y_j\tan\theta_i+x_j)=0$$

Then, the distance from the origin to this line is

$$D=\frac{y_j\tan\theta_i+x_j}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta_i}}$$

which can be simplified to

$$D=(y_j\tan\theta_i+x_j)\cos\theta_i = x_j\cos\theta_i + y_j\sin\theta_i$$

Thus the signed distance is $d_{ij}=r_i-D$, i.e.

$$d_{ij} = r_i - x_j \cos \theta_i - y_j \sin\theta_i$$

Comment: Can you please include the principle or operation behind your calculation of $D?$